# LaTeX: Put a dot next to a page number

Tags: numbers, latex

I'm currently working on my thesis, and one of the requirements is to put a dot just next to the page number (which is at the top right corner).

This is the code that I am using for the moment. It does everything that I want except for the dot...

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %Deletes the horizontal bar
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} %puts the page number to the right
```

Could someone help me with my problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you just use `\thepage.`?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like \hspace to \thepage:

```
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage \hspace{1 mm} . } %adjust 1 mm to any value as needed
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the dot after the `\thepage`;

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage.}

\begin{document}

See the page number in the top-right corner.

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: the rendered page]